# pg_dump fills up memory but does not write to disk

Tags: postgresql, backup, pg-dump

What could cause pg_dump to fill up memory and not write to disk? Strace just hangs at a certain point with no errors and database log does not show any errors. Once memory is filled up and swap is full the pg_dump process is stopped.

Comment: Use `strace -f` to follow forks.

Comment: Already tried it with strace -f and strace -ff. No errors are show. It just hangs.

Comment: Please share the relevant parts of the `strace` output.

Comment: strace -ff is huge, it just hangs and does not show errors. pg_basebackup works for now.

Comment: Perhaps you have lots of large objetcs, They tend to give a headache with `pg_dump`.